# is there a way to force iOS into using Google Maps in code?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit, cllocationmanager

Several answers to questions exist on S.O. but they don't apply to exactly what I'm asking

One answer pointed to [The Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html) but couldn't find anything useful

I've lent out an iPad for testing and the person is reporting that the terrain features are wrong. He's at the right location, but the farm buildings and cropping rows are what they were about 5 years ago. One of my older 1st issue iPads that is limited to iOS 5.1 shows things correctly to the latest.

I've worked out that since iOS6, newer iPads default to Apple's own Maps App. I've been through the internet suggestions based on Starting at Apple Maps, setting Directions between two locations and so on, and on some of my latest iPads it works, but on others it has no effect whatsoever on the app I'm writing. For my man in the field it works but if the guy doesn't use it for a few days, it defaults to Apple.

Is this a problem that someone else has solved?

( Cropping-based apps in rural areas want to be as up to date as possible so it's a bigger deal than buildings that tend to stay for 40 years or more in cities. I could jailbreak the thing but I can't expect all my eventual users to do that.)

Comment: you should use [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org), than you can fix issues in the map. Even host your own data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible. You should use the Google Maps SDK provided by Google, but it'll be a bit of a rewrite if you built your code on MapKit.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start?hl=en

Comment: I suspected as much. It was done in Objective-C, and I've started rewriting it in Swift so with a different toolset its not a line-by-line translation but a whole new approach.  But it's not too herculean a task.